# How to access the current view in the custom view?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-attributes

Suppose if i am creating a custom button. And i extend the MyCustomButton to AppCompatButton. Then how can i access the view that is currently created on screen. Because onDraw gives a canvas object, if ill do something on that canvas object then something new will be created on screen/canvas. But what i want is to do things with the button created on screen.

For example:

```
<com.abc.MycustomButton

android: layout_height:10dp
android: layout_height:10dp
/>
```

Then this will create a button since i have extended to Appcompat button, now all i want is access to this button view and make changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it directly through its id in the xml:

In XML

```
<com.abc.MycustomButton
        android:id="@+id/myCustomButton"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
```

In Java

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.myCustomButton);
// Use the view here
```